# Variable within a liquid statement

Tags: liquid

I am trying to dynamically load images from a gallery where I pass the gallery handle using a variable that's same as the current page handle. The following code does not work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
 {% assign pagehandle = page.handle %}
 {% assign thumbcounter = 0 %}{% for image in site.galleries.[pagehandle].images %}
 {% assign thumbcounter = thumbcounter | plus: 1 %}
 <a href="#{{thumbcounter}}"><img src="{{ image | gallery_asset_url}}"/></a></div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access `site.galleries[pagehandle]` if `galleries` is a hash map. Also, you don't need your own counter, you can use [`forloop.index`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/for-loops#forloop-index) as a loop counter starting at index 1.

```
{% assign pagehandle = page.handle %}
{% for image in site.galleries[pagehandle].images %}
    <a href="#{{forloop.index}}"><img src="{{ image | gallery_asset_url}}"/></a></div>
{% endfor %}
```